# Authenticate that a user has logged in with MSAL/Azure AD and serve them a token for my separate API?

Tags: go, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have an api written in GO that, at the moment, serves an authorization token based on a username and password. (Without MSAL)

I am trying to implement MSAL logins with Microsoft accounts. I have setup my angular frontend to log a user in to an Azure AD app registration. Would it be possible to authenticate that they have successfully logged in to the Azure AD, and serve them one of my tokens (unrelated to msal) from my GO API?

The username that they use to login with MSAL also exists in my backend, the flow would be something like this;

User logs in with MSAL -> my frontend makes a request to golang backend with username -> golang verifies that this username has logged in with MSAL -> backend serves a token for this user

It appears golang integration with MSAL is limited, so not sure how possible this is.

Thanks.

Comment: Here is a small Go library that can be used for validating the MSAL Identity token on the backend https://github.com/alexandervantrijffel/msidal

Comment: @AlexandervanTrijffel very useful, had to handle validation myself for this project but in the future this may be very helpful, thankyou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is acquire an access token for your API in the front-end from Azure AD. For this you will either register the API in Azure AD or use the same app registration. Either way, you should add a scope in the Expose an API page in the registration. Your front-end can then use that scope's id to get the needed token.

Your API can then have an endpoint that validates the access token, and issues the local token. The access token will contain the user's username for example, if you want to map to that. A more robust way would be to map to the user's object id (also in the token) since it is immutable, unlike the user email.

For token validation, you should be able to use a generic JWT validation library. Also remember to check for that scope in the token that you defined to properly authorize the request.

Comment: thanks! this is exactly what I needed. Related docs for anyone doing something similar: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens